# Sorting Files Array by LastModefiedTime

Tags: java, android, algorithm, sorting

I want to Sort a Files Array by lastModefiedTime from the oldest to the newest ( first Element must be the Oldest and the Last Element the newest).

i wrote this Methods but it didnt work!!

```
private static void swap(File[] files,int a, int b){
    File h = files[a];
    files[a]=files[b];
    files[b]=h;
}

public static void fillBoxList(String path){



    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {

        //Box.addToFilesArray(directoryListing[0]);
// print the List before Sorting 
        for(int i =0;i<dfiles.length;i++){
            Log.i("LastModDate", new Date(directoryListing[i].lastModified())+"");
        }
//Beginn of Sorting
        for (int i =1;i<files.length;i++) {

            Date lastModdate1 = new Date(files[i-1].lastModified());
            Date lastModDate2 = new Date(files[i].lastModified());

                 if(lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)>1){
                     swap(files,i-1,i);
                 }
        }
// print the List after Sorting
        for(int i =0;i<directoryListing.length;i++){
            Log.i("SortedLastModDate", new Date(directoryListing[i].lastModified())+"");
        }
    } else {

        Log.e("DircError","directory dont exists");
    }
}
```

can you tell me please what i did wrong?

Comment: How about converting the array to a `List`, and then sort the list in a one-liner using Java 8 Lambda? https://dzone.com/articles/using-lambda-expression-sort

Comment: i have really no idea of Lambda, i never used it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort algorithm is actually wrong. There should be two loops in a [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

```
while (true){
    boolean swapped = false;
    for (int i =1;i<files.length;i++) {
        Date lastModdate1 = new Date(files[i-1].lastModified());
        Date lastModDate2 = new Date(files[i].lastModified());
        if(lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)>1){
              swap(files,i-1,i);
              swapped = true;
        }
    }
    if ( !swapped )
      break;
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution. when i did it with lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)>1 i got the newest as first element. so i change it to lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)<1 and i got an endless Loop!!

Comment: `lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)<1` will result in an endless loop if there two elements are equal in the list. use: `lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)<0`

Comment: and what should i do in this case?

Comment: use this: `lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)<0`

Comment: the correct way to get the List be sorted from the oldest to newest is lastModdate1.compareTo(lastModDate2)>0. my Mistake was that i compare with 1!! thank you my friend you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first check what value is comparision statements returning

```
int comparison = date.compareTo(date2);
```

int comparison2 = date2.compareTo(date);
   int comparison3 = date.compareTo(date);

Log those int variables, then check how to sort, or may be your date is not properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Java 8 approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Stream<File> sortedFiles = getSortedFiles("src/main/resources");
    sortedFiles.forEach(f ->
        System.out.printf("File: %s, last modified %s \n", f.getName(), new Date(f.lastModified()))
    );
}

public static Stream<File> getSortedFiles(String path) throws IOException {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<Path> list = Files.list(Paths.get(path))) {
        list.map(Path::toFile)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified))
                .forEach(files::add);
    }
    return files.stream();
}
```

Comment: we use java 7 for our project

Answer (score -1):

you could write a `java.util.Comparator` which compares `LastModefiedTime` and than sort your array with `java.utils.Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c))`.
You do not need to implement sorting on your own.